# Android equivalent of UIEdgeInset

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable

I have an image with rounded corners. I need to stretch the image without warping the corners. (basically I just want to stretch the middle)

In iOS I would do something along the lines of

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5)];
```

How would I go about doing the same on android.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done in Android by using 9-patch drawable with specifying the stretchable area for your image for more details you can see the documentation on the Android Developer [website](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)